# Type special characters in iTerm2: Dead keys seem to be ignored

Tags: keyboard, iterm, keybindings

How to type special characters in iTerm2 using dead keys, e.g. typing

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>e</kbd>  + <kbd>e</kbd>  should give é

also in iTerm.

Note, there is a workaround as in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440335/286394, which essentially changes the *Input Source* to *US International PC*. This allows to type

<kbd>'</kbd>  +  <kbd>e</kbd>  which gives é

Other Mac apps work properly, just not iTerm. Is there a setting or change I might make to get this working?

Comment: Have you tested to see if Apple’s native terminal.app or notes.app works? Knowing if this is system general or iTerm specific might help narrow the fix.

Comment: @bmike, yes I tested it with the terminal.app, there it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default iTerm2 is configured to send Esc+ by Altgr. So just switch it to Normal as on my screenshot.

[image: Settings]

Comment: This indeed works. The corresponding config settings are: `"Right Option Key Sends" : 2, "Option Key Sends" : 2,` with `0` for `Normal` and `2` for `Esc+`.